# How to send date to node from angular?

Tags: date

When am passing date from angular to node I found my date was decremented by 1 day and passed to the node,why this was happening? and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Give more informations. Environment, Language, Your problem and question. And see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Raghu, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your question is too vague; with the information you've given us, there could be any number of different answers. Could you let us know a bit more about the system you're implementing, and if possible post a small example of the code which illustrates the problem?